# Don't upload file across nginx with help the upload module

Tags: django, upload, module, nginx

In my project there was a problem. Don't upload file. Here is my code

config nginx

```
server{

listen 9000;
server_name localhost;
root  /home/path/my/project;

location ~ ^/(static|media)/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

location /file-upload {
    internal;
    upload_pass /upload-file/;
    upload_store /home/payh/my/project/media/video;
    upload_max_file_size 250m;

    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
    upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";

    upload_pass_form_field "^csrfmiddlewaretoken$";

    upload_limit_rate 2m;
    track_uploads upload 1m;
}

location = /upload/progress {
    report_uploads upload;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_connect_timeout 10;
    proxy_read_timeout 10;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
}
error_page 500 502 503 504 /media/50x.html;
}
```

Request come in function by nginx_accel after click in button upload. Then view create response for nginx and send it. Nginx return 405 not allowed. I don't why.
my views.py

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def upload(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pathfile = request.POST.get('upfile.path')
        upfile   = open(pathfile, 'r')
        file = File(upfile)

        form = NewFileForm(request.POST, initial={'upfile':file})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(upload))
    else:
        form = NewFileForm()

    return render_to_response('upload.html', 
                          {'form':form},
                           context_instance=context)    
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def nginx_accel(request):
    if request.user.id == 1:
        file = request.FILES.get('upfile').name
        url = '/'.join(['/file-upload', file])
        response = HttpResponse()

        response['Content-Type']= ''
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url

        return response
```

Nginx in browser return "405 Not allowed". Can anyone say why this problem appear?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the error is this `file = request.FILES.get('upfile').name`. It will bypass and attempt to serve the static file on a POST request, resulting in a 405 error. To fix your problem.

```
@login_required
@csrf_protect
def nginx_accel(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        if request.user.id == 1:
            file = request.GET.get('upfile').name
            url = '/'.join(['/file-upload', file])
            response = HttpResponse()

            response['Content-Type']= ''
            response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = url

            return response
```

Answer (score 0):

try: remove string  internal;
in location /file-upload
If a request has a method other than POST, the module returns error 405 (Method not allowed). Requests with such methods could be processed in alternative location via error_page directive.     [more info](http://www.grid.net.ru/nginx/upload.en.html)